# What is the default directory of Template Processor in PHPWord?

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpword

I am using PHPword to generate the word documents. I want to generate multiple documents so that I want to use the template. I tried this code in the controller:

```
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');
$templateProcessor->setValue('Name', 'John Doe');
$templateProcessor->setValue(array('City', 'Street'), array('Detroit', '12th Street'));
```

and following error is displayed:

```
copy(resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory
```

at :

```
// Template file cloning
if (false === copy($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename)) {
throw new CopyFileException($documentTemplate, $this->tempDocumentFilename);
}
```

What is the default directory of Template Processor? or we have to give location manually. Please help!

PHP version:7.0 
laravel 5.5
PHPWord version: 0.14

Comment: Where is this controller file in relation to the `resources` folder? are you sure you have the path correct? Maybe a quick `__DIR__ . '/resources/Sample....` is the way to go?

Comment: Controller file is in the App\Http\Controllers. and resources folder is in Vendor\phpoffice\phpword\samples\resources.

Comment: And where is the resources folder?

Comment: Resources folder is in Vendor\phpoffice\phpword\samples\resources. How to link between controller and Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx file??

Comment: I think this is the path you need... `__DIR__ . '/../../../Vendor/phpoffice/phpword/samples/resources/yourfilehere'`

Comment: I would advise putting you template in a nicer spot, that's one hell of a path!

Comment: It is the default location of template . I tried this              $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('../../../vendor/phpoffice/phpword/samples/resources/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx');  but it doesnot work error is same. Where i should put Template then??

Comment: Put it anywhere you like, it's just a sample template file right? try putting it the root of your project and see if can be found at all, then put it somewhere sensible and update your path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Worked For me:
Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx to be inside /storage directory instead. And using this line:

```
$templateProcessor = new 
TemplateProcessor(storage_path('Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.docx'));
```